# Read data from System objects in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using the Foreground Detection example in Matlab, using Gaussian Mixture Models, given in this [link](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.foregrounddetector-class.html)

Part of the code where the foreground detection is done, is given below

```
    videoSource = vision.VideoFileReader('viptraffic.avi',...
    'ImageColorSpace','Intensity','VideoOutputDataType','uint8');

    detector = vision.ForegroundDetector(...
   'NumTrainingFrames', 5, ...
   'InitialVariance', 30*30);
```

The system object **detector** has the foreground mask. Simply put, How do I access this mask from the system object?

It is possible to use other methods of the class, which make use of the mask computed. But I am not able to find a way to get this mask out and use it for my own code/purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/detecting-cars-using-gaussian-mixture-models.html) has a work around for this. The foreground mask is able to be retrieved as an image, and hence the pixels.